# Alternative to "Decreased Productivity" browser extension

Tags: web-browser, css, privacy

I used to have the [Decreased Productivity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/decreased-productivity) browser extension (Firefox only) installed, but when looking it up now, it seems that the project has been abandoned (no update since 2010) and it's no longer compatible with recent versions of Firefox.

The main thing that the extension does is to:

- hide or dim images (showing them with a simple mouseover)
- reformat text

Here's an excerpt of an [article](http://lifehacker.com/5421669/decreased-productivity-helps-you-browse-at-work-without-getting-busted) on Lifehacker about *Decreased Productivity*:

> Decreased Productivity adds a small toolset to your Firefox browser
>   that, once activated, drops a style sheet over the web page you're
>   looking at that washes out the images and converts all the text to a
>   plain, boring font. Anyone who glances at your screen as they walk by
>   won't have a clue what web sites you're visiting and when the coast is
>   clear just hover your mouse over the image place holders to see them
>   again.

If possible, I'd like to find an extension with a similar set of features, ideally not limited to a single browser.

Comment: Firefox has a "reading mode" now that makes the page black on white and removes much of the clutter, but not the main images. The button is to the right of the URL.

Comment: Your boss was already notified :C)

Answer (score 1):

Opera 12.x has customizable toolbar buttons to reformat pages and hide/show images. Opera browser has became a Chrome clone but I still use the old Presto version. I have a firewall and don't visit harmful websites. So,  Opera 12.x can be my main browser I use. For sites that Opera can't display, I use the "Open with" option to load Firefox. If you can find the downloader, it should be fine for this purpose. You need to enable the menu bar, toolbar and add those buttons using the Customize option. (Websites that curate old versions may have the installer.)

[image: Just tap the button to toggle images]

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox use this style https://userstyles.org/styles/45771/work-safe-mode
with the [Stylish Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Indeed, that answers the question. May I suggest making this a [high quality answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/185) by [edit]ing it and add some more details of what it is and what it does -- plus what makes this better than Firefox' built-in reading mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the same extension on Chrome =) latest update two months ago ... July 25, 2016
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decreased-productivity/nlbpiflhmdcklcbihngeffpmoklbiooj?hl=en

If you want to use it in Opera the following extension will help you:
https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/

Hope it helps you all ... I love this extension =)